# Vuejs doesn't render components inside HTML table elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to render a custom component that displays a row inside a table.

I have the following code:

```
// js file
Vue.component('message-row', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            msg: 'Hello'
        }
    },
    template: '<tr><td>{{ msg }}</td></tr>'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});


// html file
<div id="app">
    <table><message-row></message-row></table>
</div>
```

The problem is that the row ends up rendered outside the table! Like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <table></table>
</div>
```

You can check it out in this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eciii/7v6yrf3x/

I'm not sure if this is a bug or I'm just missing something really obvious here...

Comment: The browser tries to "fix" your HTML by moving the unknown tag out of the table, before Vue has a chance to change it.

Comment: @ChrisG Do you know a solution? The main point of using components is to be able to use them like this isn't it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See Vue.js's documentation about [DOM Template Parsing Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats):

> Some HTML elements, such as `<ul>`, `<ol>`, `<table>` and `<select>` have restrictions on what elements can appear inside them, and some elements such as `<li>`, `<tr>`, and `<option>` can only appear inside certain other elements.
>
> This will lead to issues when using components with elements that have such restrictions. For example:
>
> ```
> <table>
>   <blog-post-row></blog-post-row>
> </table>
> ```
>
> The custom component `<blog-post-row>` will be hoisted out as invalid
> content, causing errors in the eventual rendered output. Fortunately,
> the `is` special attribute offers a workaround:
>
> ```
> <table>
>   <tr is="blog-post-row"></tr>
> </table>
> ```

You need to add the component using the `is` attribute as follows.

```
<table><tr is="message-row"></tr></table>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/7v6yrf3x/1/.

Comment: Great! I just missed that part of the documentation.

Comment: Answer was helpful. Thanks! But how can I pass props?

Comment: @M.Islam Like always: `<tr is="blog-post-row" prop1="text" :prop2="var"></tr>`

Comment: jsfiddle links are not working. Where should I add is="" ? Do I add it in the html file or inside the component in JS file. Do I add seperate <tr> tag or just add is=" " to existing <tr> tag. Thanks

Comment: I accidentally got it :
<message-row></message-row> becomes <tr is="message-row"> </tr>

Comment: Note from the documentation: "When used on native HTML elements, the value of is must be prefixed with vue: in order to be interpreted as a Vue component.", so it becomes: <tr is="vue:blog-post-row"></tr>